# text3D rising or descending with same zdir matplotlib python plot figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, figure, direction

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x= [-1,-0.5, 0.5, 0.5] 
y= [1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1]
z= [1, 0.75, 0.5,0.25]
tags = ['tag1','tag2','tag3','tag4']

az = -45
el = 45
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(azim=az, elev= el)
ax.scatter(x, y ,z, s=20)
for x1, y1, z1,tag in zip(x,y,z,tags):
    ax.text3D(x1, y1, z1, tag, zdir='z')
```

In Python, Matplotlib I create a scatter plot and I want to tag all the points.

For ease of read I want them to be all vertical and rising.

But in the solution I wrote, the text appears rising on the right and descending on the left. I wish it to be the same all over and `zdir` is vertical.

Only when the elevation is set to zero do the tag rise.

Comment: I fear there might be a bug somewhere in matplotlib. Would you be able to make this a [mcve] in the sense of not having one page of data values in it? Does this also happen with the default `view_init`? Does it also happen if the x axis is positive? You could then directly report to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).

Comment: looks like a bug to me as well. I'm working on the minimal example. if I set the elevation to zero then the text is all rising

Comment: xref: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11804

Comment: we have a partial fix: use orthographic 3D rather than perspective:https://matplotlib.org/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_2.1.0.html#orthographic-projection-for-mplot3d